# How can I program vncserver to automatically setup my shells for me?

Tags: terminal, x11, vnc

I use VNC to connect to a hosted machine. Whenever I start a VNC server at some port and connect to it, I first need to setup my shells for me - 5 of them in a particular configuration that I like and then start my work.

Is there a way to automate this task so that whenever a VNC server is started, my shells are already configured and ready for me to use?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried creating

```
~/.vncstartup
```

or

```
~/.vnc/xstartup
```

In my version of `vncserver`, that's where you put your startup commands, e.g.

```
xterm -geometry 80x25+0+0 &
xterm ...
...
```

See also [Taking your desktop virtual with VNC](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/006apr05/features/vnc).